# How to diff a file and output from the command?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

Normally you would write:

```
diff file1 file2
```

But I would like to diff a file and output from the command (here I make command a trivial one):

```
diff file1 <(cat file2 | sort)
```

Ok, this work when I enter this manually at shell prompt, but when I put exactly the same line in shell script, and then run the script, I get error.

So, the question is -- how to do this correctly?

*Of course I would like avoid writing the output to a temporary file.*

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I suspect your script and your shell are different. Perhaps you have `#!/bin/sh` at the top of your script as the interpreter but you are using `bash` as your personal shell. You can find out what shell you run in a terminal by running `echo $SHELL`.

An easier way to do this which should work across most shells would be to use a pipe redirect instead of the file read operator you give. The symbol '-' is a standard nomenclature for reading STDIN and can frequently be used as a replacement for a file name in an argument list:

```
cat file2 | sort | diff file1 -
```

Or to avoid a [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html):

```
sort < file2 | diff file1 -
```

Comment: Ah, you are good, indeed, I didn't check if sh is bash or not. Thank you very much for the solution.

Comment: It is diffing file with stdout. Now how to diff stdout with a file? I mean, the opposite direction. it's `-R` in case of using `git diff --no-index`

Comment: @Nakilon You would just change the argument order: `diff - file1`.

Comment: Cool. This didn't work for `git diff`.

Comment: @Nakilon Of course not, why would it? `git diff` is a completely different beast and operates on references to glob objects in its internal index, not files; `diff` operates on the file system. The `-` syntax is just shell syntactic sugar for `/dev/stdin`, the file representing the STDIN stream. Hence why `diff` can use it as a substitute for a file name. Meanwhile `git diff` isn't looking for files, it's looking up objects so you have to pass it something it recognizes. Don't use it to compare files to each other, use `diff` for that.

Answer (score -3):

The scope of the standard input it's the script itself, so just put your code inside a blocku like this:

```
{
  diff file1 <(sort file2)
}
```

In this way the scope of the STDIN it's  inside the block..

I've tried and it works.

Comment: That's not a function, it's a block, and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @gilles Thx for the correction. BTW I've tried myself and it works. Did you?

Comment: The block doesn't have any effect on the validity of the `<(…)` construct. Your script will work or not work depending on whether you run it in a shell that supports `<(…)` or not (ksh93/bash/zsh vs Bourne/ash/kshk88). [Caleb's answer nails it all.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11733/how-to-diff-a-file-and-output-from-the-command/11734#11734)

Comment: @gilles ok, thx for the explanation.