# Killing a process and diffing its result

Tags: bash, scripting

I've been trying to write a simple bash script, but I cannot get it to work.

I want to:

- Start a program, feeding it input from a text file (`./prog < input1.txt`)
- Wait a short amount of time and the kill it as if it was served a keyboard interrupt (`& PID=$!; sleep 1; kill -INT $PID`) [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5789674)
- Find the differences between the program's output and a text file (`| diff -y output1.txt -`) [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11734)

Here's what I have now, putting the previous steps together:

`./program < input1.txt & PID=$!; sleep 1; kill -INT $PID | diff -y output1.txt -`

This version always reports  that the first command has had no output, since the PID line is shadowing it. If I add even a file redirect after the program name, the kill command stops working since it is now pointing at the redirect.

Edit: I am on Ubuntu 16.04; the output of `bash --version` is `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: `{ ./program < input1.txt & PID=$!; sleep 1; kill -INT $PID; }| diff -y output1.txt -`

Comment: @WeijunZhou that stops the kill command from happening by blocking the PID assignment somehow

Comment: How about `bash -c './program < input1.txt & PID=$!; sleep 1; kill -INT $PID; '| diff -y output1.txt`. I have tested both solutions using `yes` as `./program`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou The second solution also causes a hang for me, including when testing with `yes`

Comment: I missed the final hyphen. Sorry about it. Should be `diff -y output1.txt -`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou yea, I added it in when I tested. The problem is that using the output in some way appears to stop me from killing the process. Can you check that the output of `yes` is being recorded in some way?

Comment: Issues with `diff`. `cat` works fine.

Comment: @WeijunZhou You are right, cat shows both outputs. Unfortunately, the kill command no longer works, suggesting diff waits for the output to be complete while cat is able to work on running files.

Comment: I played with some other command that generates far less data than `yes` and it worked (more specifically, `base64 /dev/urandom`). I don't know how many data `./program` is generating. You may also try turning off buffering with `stdbuf`.

Comment: I tried `<()` hours ago, also failed with `yes`.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, in your code `diff` receives the output of `kill` instead of `program`. You can solve this by compounding the commands before the pipe in a subshell with `()`.

Another potential issue with your script is that `kill` is not designed to wait for termination of `program`; instead it just sends a signal to it. Therefore you may see a race condition where `diff` works without catching the whole output of `program`. I advice to programatically wait for termination of the backgound process with the `wait` bash builtin.

Here goes a sample of your code containing the above fixes:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
    ./program <input1.txt &
    PID=$!
    sleep 1
    kill -INT $PID
    wait
) | diff -y reference_output.txt -
```

Comment: There is no termination of the background program, that's why I want to send a SIGSEV. The program expects to be ended early by the user pressing CTRL-C, so waiting will wait forever.

Comment: I see. In this case the wait is not required.

Comment: @AlexVermillion The `wait` will not wait forever if there's no background tasks to wait for. In the submitted code, the `wait` would wait for the task to terminate (it may do some cleanup or processing when it receives the `INT` signal, which may take a bit of time).

Comment: @Kusalananda In this case, it does wait forever. For some reason, although the parenthesis block is being exited, the program is not actually being killed. I can tell by checking `top` after and seeing it is still running. I am confused, because running the `kill -INT $PID` on the command line after properly setting the variable does kill it. I can tell that the kill command is passed by putting a `touch blah.txt` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a process substitution[1]:

```
diff -y output1.txt <(your_program & sleep 1; kill $!)
```

If `your_program` is able to generate huge amounts of data in a second (as when testing with `yes(1)`), then `diff` will have a lot of trouble coping with, and unless you have some careful limits put in place, it may blow your memory and hang up your machine (and in the best case it will create the illusion that the command is "hanging" for a while). Instead of `yes`, try it with a `slowyes` script like `while echo y; do sleep .01; done`.

Notice that a `<(...)` process substitution runs **in parallel**, so `diff` will not wait for it to finish before starting to process its data.

I guess you will be better served by stopping `your_program` after it has generated a number of lines, instead of after a period of time:

```
diff -y output1.txt <(your_program | head -n 1000)
```

In this case, `your_program` should be killed by `SIGPIPE`, as usual with the left side of a pipeline. If your program is ignoring both `SIGPIPE` and `write(2)` errors, then please make another question about that, either how to fix it or how to work it around.

[1] if your shell does not support process substitutions (as the `/bin/sh` on debian, which is not `bash`), you can also use a pipeline, as in the other answer

```
{ your_program & sleep 1; kill $!; } | diff -y output1.txt -
```

the same caveats apply to this case, too.

Comment: The output of running the program is silenced in the first command since it is hidden behind a semicolon.
I did not test the second as the program has 3 lines of output only.
The third snippet fails for the same reason as the first.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide an exact snippet you have tested this with? When I test with yes, there is not any output, which is the only part I am having a problem with as the rest works.

Comment: "The output of running the program is silenced in the first command since it is hidden behind a semicolon". No. That's not how it works. The semicolon doesn't hide anything. You can try with any program you want -- it will work exactly as I described, including why there's "no output" with `yes(1)`.

Comment: @AlexVermillion There are a lot of reasons why `your_program` could fail to produce any output; for instance, it may use buffering when not outputting to a terminal, and not flush its buffers when killed by a signal. But there are thousands of possible scenarios like that.

Comment: I have been running these commands and taking my best guess at what silences them. It's a very short C program that terminates when fed a certain letter or else does a simple array operation. It will not terminate if left alone, but the output that I know is happening does not show in the diff, only when followed by other commands, as if its stdout is ignored by the pipe.

Comment: If it's printing with stdio funcs (printf, puts, fputc, etc) then you can try running it `stdbuf -oL ./prog` (`stdbuf` is a GNU coreutils program)