# How do I compare a command output to a text file?

Tags: bash, diff

I am learning some programming interview questions so I've coded FizzBuzz. I'm trying to comprare the output of my program to a known good output that's in a .txt file.

How do I check that `node fizzbuzz.js` output is line by line equal to a `expected-output.txt` file, or even `diff` them?

I've tried this as suggested in the duplicate question:

`diff -u expected-output.txt <(node fizzbuzz.js)`

but `diff` outputs nothing and never seems to quit until I `^C`. The program by itself runs fine, and so does `diff -u expected-output.txt <(cat test.txt)`, it just doesn't seem to play well with `node` for some reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11733/342404

Comment: Note: Unix does not have text files, they are just files. Text file were from CP/M, then MS-Dos adopted the idea, even though it did not really have a difference between text and binary files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to diff a file and output from the command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11733/how-to-diff-a-file-and-output-from-the-command)

Comment: Hmm, I can't see why node.js would break with process substitution. A quick test works on my machine. Does running `node fizzbuzz.js > output.txt; diff -u expected-output.txt output.txt` work? If you can't get the process subst working, you might want to post another question about that (and include your version of `node` and a full `.js` script)

Comment: @ilkkachu yeah, your command works fine. I'm using `console.log()` to print from my loop so maybe the process substitution never ends?

Comment: I've posted here also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530129/process-substitution-with-doesnt-work-with-diff-and-node

Comment: @ChefTony, well, if the program ever finishes, the process substitution pipes would close and `diff` would see end-of-file there. Getting it left hanging would pretty much need starting some background process with a copy of the pipe file descriptors...

Answer (score 11):

In Bash/ksh/Zsh:

```
diff -u file.txt <(some command)
```

The `<(some command)` construct is called [process substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), and it makes the output from *some command* available as if from a file, so `diff` can read it. (It sets up pipes from the command and expands to the name of a named pipe or `/dev/fd/N`).

Similarly, `>(some command)` could be used to redirect writes *to* the command.