# Process substitution doesn't work with diff and node

Tags: bash, diff, process-substitution

I'm trying to compare the output of my `fizzbuzz.js` program:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  let out = "";
  if (i % 3 == 0) out += "Fizz";
  if (i % 5 == 0) out += "Buzz";
  if (i % 3 && i % 5) out = i;
  console.log(out);
}
```

with the contents of a `expected-output.txt` file which contains:

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
[...]
```

I can't get process substitution to work:

```
diff -u expected-output.txt <(node fizzbuzz.js)
```

seems to hang indefinitely. What could be causing this?

My environment is macOS Mojave, bash 3.2.57, node v12.5.0.

EDIT: this seems to be a macOS issue. Everything works fine on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine with newer bash 4.4.19

Comment: Thanks for the negative vote. I thought you know how to call diff and it's just about the process substitution, as the title suggests. Make your questions clearer. That will increase your chances of getting an appropriate answer. I'll not investigate further here.

Comment: @jottbe I didn't give you a negative vote

Comment: @jottbe : *I* did give the negative note, because it was not a correct *answer* and not even a correct *comment*.

Comment: Does the command `diff -u expected-output.txt <(cat expected-output.txt)` terminate correctly?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli It does (exit code 0)

Comment: As I've added in the post, this only seems to happen on macOS. Maybe it's the older bash version?

Comment: Can you try `node fizzbuzz.js | diff -u expected-output.txt -`?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli that works! Thanks!

Comment: Probably you bumped to the "seek problem" explained in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164107/why-does-bash-process-substitution-not-work-with-some-commands

Comment: Because `read var <(echo hello)` didn't work as command substitution, but `read var < <(echo hello)` does, I thought that was the problem. And @ChefTony comments help some times. At least for those who are fair and have the courage! thanks

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, nah, `diff` shouldn't need to seek. And if it did, it would probably give a clear error about it anyway.

Comment: @jottbe, yeah, `read` reads from stdin, but `diff` expects a filename. The `<(...)` expands to a file name, so can be used as-is with `diff`. On the other hand, `< <(...)`  redirects to stdin from that "file"

Comment: Obviously, there is some difference between the `cat` command and the `node` command here. Since I have no access to a system similar to the OP's, I cannot do my own tests.

Comment: will `cat <(node fizzbuzz.js)` hang too? also, what does `ls -l <(true)` say (I don't know about MacOS, but on some systems, bash will use named pipes for process substitutions).

Comment: @mosvy yes, `cat <(node fizzbuzz.js)` hangs too, it displays the output but doesn't exit until I `^C`. `ls -l <(true)` returns `prw-rw----  0 user  staff  0 Jul 15 06:29 /dev/fd/63`